# Python process Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking through the Python docs and found a function called `process`. I have only seen it in use in the documentation of other features but it itself is not documented, as far as I can tell.

Here are some examples from the documentation of when it is used.

From [`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=process#typing.overload):

```
@overload
def process(response: None) -> None:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: int) -> Tuple[int, str]:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: bytes) -> str:
    ...
def process(response):
    <actual implementation>
```

From [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html?highlight=process):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

And finally, from [`Match objects`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=process#match-objects)

```
match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    process(match)
```

I am specifically interested in the last usage. My question is this, what is this `process` function and where is the documentation for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases, `process` is just an arbitrary name for an example placeholder function  used to demonstrate example uses of the things being documented. You will often see variables and functions like `foo`, `process`, `bar`, `do_something`. Generally, if it's a generic named function/variable that isn't the specific thing being documented and isn't defined elsewhere, it will be a placeholder.

For example, the last case could be written, perhaps more clearly (and verbosely), like:

```
match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    # placeholder
    # here is where you can be sure `match` is not None
    # and you can use it in your code, for example:
    process(match)
```

Answer (score 2):

### What is the process function ?

It is a placeholder, it doesn't exist (unless you define it).

It is the equivalent of saying `# Your code goes here`, but it indicates the target object (`line`, `match` ...) which will be used by the user.

### Example

```
match = re.search(pattern, string)
if match:
    process(match)
```

It means, *"this is how match work and should be used, do anything you want with the **match** object"*